# Set a yelp link to display from a random array

Tags: android, random, google-maps-android-api-2, textview

How do I display a YELP link for the food truck that is selected. My app randomly selects a food truck to eat at.

Food truck names are stored in an array. 
i.e: NYC Halal is selected. Now I need to display the YELP link that is associated with it.

Randomizer.java //Randomly selects a food truck to eat

```
public class Randomizer extends AppCompatActivity {
final String[] places = {
        "VeganTree", "Tommy's", "Tabeteki", "Korea House", "Halal Kebab King", "El Guaco Loco",
        "Burger Tank","The Creperie Truck","Ray's Truck","Top Bap","Samosa Deb",
        "Honey","Richie's LunchBox","Natasha's Caribbean Cafe","Foot Long","Brother's Pizza",
        "Philly Fellas Gyro Halal","TJ's Corner","Simply Yummy","Jamaican D's","Cha Cha","","Chop Chop",
        "Kobawoo Express","Chicken Heaven","E&E Gourmet Express","Eppy's Truck","Ernie's","Sexy Green Truck",
        "Eddie's","Sunny Halal Food","Caribbean Feast","Ebi's Lunch Truck (Halal)","Famous NY Gyro (Halal)",
        "Halal Gyro Express","Mexican Grill Stand","Mountain Pizza",
};
Button maps;
Button randomize;
TextView place;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_randomize2);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    final int[] randomPosition = new int[1]; // Add this

    place = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place);

    final Random random = new Random();
    randomPosition[0] = random.nextInt(places.length);
    place.setText(places[randomPosition[0]]);

    maps = (Button) findViewById(R.id.maps);
    maps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String randomRestaurant = places[randomPosition[0]];

            Intent showMap = new Intent(Randomizer.this, RestaurantMaps.class);
            showMap.putExtra(RestaurantMaps.EXTRA_SELECTED_RESTAURANT,
                    randomRestaurant);
            startActivity(showMap);
        }
    });

    randomize = (Button) findViewById(R.id.randomize);
    randomize.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            randomPosition[0] = random.nextInt(places.length);
            place.setText(places[randomPosition[0]]);
        }
    });



}
}
```